# Titanium iOS : Show window on top

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I am created 3 windows A,B,C. Window B is opened from window A. And window C from window B.

But the thing is window C is shown in between A & B. I want this window to be shown on top of B. Works fine in android, but not in iOS.

Following is the code :
1. Window A

```
var chatBoxWindow = Titanium.UI.createWindow({
        top : Ti.API.top,
        url : '',
        left : '100%',
        width : '100%',
        zIndex : 100,
        orientationModes : [Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_LEFT, Ti.UI.LANDSCAPE_RIGHT, Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT]
    });
chatBoxWindow.open();
```

1. Window B

   var modal = require("/ui/common/smileypopup").modalWin;
   var popupWin = new modal();
   popupWin.open();
2. Window C(Smiley Picker)

   backgroundColor : 'transparent',
   id                : 'popupWin'

Comment: Could you show the image and code

Comment: Actually code is too big to paste. Creating a smiley picker(window C).But this window is not shown on top. Do you want the smiley window code ??

Comment: just the code how you are opening the windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does Window C have to be a window? Based on your code, I can't really tell. So with that assumption, see if the following helps:

What about creating a *View* for C as a commonJS file and call that inside of Window B:

```
//Code for Smileypopup which is really just a view

function Smileypopup(){

    var self = Ti.UI.createView({

        top:0,width:Ti.UI.FILL,height:Ti.UI.FILL,
        backgroundColor:'transparent',
        id:'smileypopup'
    });
    //add your smiley code picker code along with
    //your functions using the self.functionname(){}; approach

    return self;
}
module.exports = Smileypopup;
```

Then inside of Window B commonJS call *WindowC*:

```
function WindowB(){

    var Smileypopup = require('/ui/common/Smileypopup');
    var popup = new Smileypopup();

    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({});

        self.add(popup);
        self.showPopup = function(){ popup.show(); };
        self.hidePopup = function(){ popup.hide(); };

    return self;
}
module.exports = WindowB;
```

Finally, inside of Window A you can proceed as usual. It sounds like C can be a view instead of creating another Window.